# How often do ICD codes reflect the actual diagnosis in EHR?

Tags: statistics, diagnosis, health-informatics, medical-records, icd-intrntl-classif-disea

Electronic health records (EHRs) often contains ICD codes used for billing purpose. Is there any study/survey that looked at how often ICD codes in EHRs reflect the actual diagnosis?

Comment: I'm not aware of a published study. It would be hard to get buy in from a practice to conduct this study because if the ICD codes did *not* match the EHR, the practice would be guilty of fraud.

Answer (score 3):

In many cases they do reflect the actual diagnosis. 
It depends on the disease in question.

- eMerge network work on validation is for example here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3715338. In that study, they used ICD-based definitions but also other available data.
- Similar work in diabetes mellitus diagnosis is also published (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4416392/)
- Validation research tries to arrive at positive predictive value. E.g., https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/30480162
- In Japan, the PPV for AMI was 82.5%. (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/30477501)

Comment: Nice job of editing, Frank. UserJT, please use this as an example of what good supporting references look like.